# How to obtain the Assert JClass in CodeModel?

Tags: java, junit, assert, sun-codemodel

The `org.junit` package defines the `Assert` class for JUnit testing. How can I retrieve this static class as a `JClass` in the `CodeModel` framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
    import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    ...

    JCodeModel jcm = new JCodeModel();
    assertClass = jcm.ref(Assert.class);
```